# Extract the text between all sets of brackets

Tags: python, string

In Python, how do I turn this:

```
"(test1)(test2)"
```

into this:

```
["test1","test2"]
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` here for a regex approach:

```py
inp = "(test1)(test2)"
parts = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', inp)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['test1', 'test2']
```

I am assuming here that your expected output be a list of strings.

Comment: A slightly more efficient pattern is to use `[^)]*` inside of the group (instead of `.*?`)

Answer (score 0):

Split, replace, filter and attack! (Basically regex might not be allowed for you)

```
s = "(test1)(test2)"
print([x for x in s.replace("(","").split(")") if x != ''])
```